# Counting and grouping across a junk dimension

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, data-warehouse, olap

Every year we collect employee data from Government departments, which is transformed from staging and stored in a table - Employee_Fact.  This table holds a unique employee ID as well as the employee’s current leave balances for seven leave related items.  To keep it a bit simpler for my question, I am only including three here; sick leave, recreation leave and carer’s leave.

Most employees have a numeric value in these leave attributes (valid value), however some employees are not entitled to certain types of leave (not applicable), or the employer hasn’t put their leave entitlements in the system (missing), or they don’t want to disclose their leave balances (withdrawn).  Unfortunately, someone decided to codify these type of values as negative numbers. So, as an example, an employee for whom sick leave is missing will initially have, in the staging table,  -7777 in their sick leave column (or -8888 for not applicable, or -9999 for withdrawn).  This codification applies across the seven leave-related columns.

When the data is transformed and pushed to the Employee_Fact table, these negative values are nullified so that they cannot accidentally be included in a sum of legitimate numeric leave values, and the fact table looks like this.

| Employee_PK | Rec_Leave_Balance | Sick_Leave_Balance | Carers_Leave_Balance | Employee_Leave_SK | Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 10 | 20 | 15 | 1 | 2020 |
| 102 | NULL | 14 | NULL | 2 | 2020 |
| 103 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 3 | 2020 |
| 104 | 15 | 17 | 19 | 1 | 2020 |
| 105 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 4 | 2020 |
| 101 | 10 | NULL | 20 | 5 | 2021 |
| 102 | 15 | NULL | 18 | 5 | 2021 |
| 103 | NULL | NULL | 20 | 6 | 2021 |
| 104 | 12 | 44 | NULL | 7 | 2021 |
| 105 | NULL | NULL | 5 | 6 | 2021 |

However, there is still a need to find out how many employees had ‘missing’, ‘Not applicable’ etc for each leave item each year.  To accomplish this an Employee_Leave dimension was created with all the possible combinations of seven leave items an employee may have.  The PK in this dimension is a surrogate key in the Employee_Fact table.  There are 78,000 or so possible combinations in the dimension because each leave item can be classed as a valid value, missing, not applicable or withdrawn.  A simplified version of the Employee_Leave dimension table looks like this:

| Employee_Leave_PK | Sick_Leave_Code | Sick_Leave_Desc | Recreation_Leave_Code | Recreation_Leave_Desc | Carers_Leave_Code | Carers_Leave_Desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Valid value | 0 | Valid value | 0 | Valid value |
| 2 | -7777 | Missing | 0 | Valid value | -7777 | Missing |
| 3 | -7777 | Missing | -7777 | Missing | -7777 | Missing |
| 4 | -8888 | Not applicable | -8888 | Not applicable | -8888 | Not applicable |
| 5 | 0 | Valid value | -7777 | Missing | 0 | Valid value |
| 6 | -9999 | Withdrawn | -9999 | Withdrawn | 0 | Valid value |
| 7 | 0 | Valid value | 0 | Valid value | -8888 | Not applicable |

I have been asked to show the counts of Missing, Not applicable and Withdrawn values in each leave category in a QlikView document and I want to cross check the numbers with a SQL query.

This code, using a union query, gives me the result set below but I wondered if there is a better way to do this which will give me the Rows as columns and the counts and years as values.  I don't think a pivot works because I have multiple fields to pivot on.

```
`
SELECT [Period],
Case 
WHEN Sick_Leave_Desc like 'Missing' then 'Sick Leave - Missing'
WHEN Sick_leave_Desc like 'Not Applicable' then 'Sick Leave - Not applicable'
WHEN Sick_leave_Desc like 'Withdrawn' then 'Sick Leave - Withdrawn'
WHEN Sick_Leave_Desc like 'Valid Value' then 'Sick Leave - Valid Value'
END
AS Leave_type_value,
COUNT(Employee_PK) AS Total_Employees FROM
DM.FACT_EMPLOYEE_TEST FE
INNER JOIN
DM.DIM_EMPLOYEE_LEAVE DE
ON FE.Employee_Leave_SK=DE.Employee_Leave_PK
GROUP BY 
[Period],Sick_Leave_Desc

UNION ALL

SELECT [Period],
Case 
WHEN DE.Recreation_Leave_Desc like 'Missing' then 'Recreation Leave - Missing'
WHEN DE.Recreation_Leave_Desc like 'Not Applicable' then 'Recreation Leave - Not applicable'
WHEN DE.Recreation_Leave_Desc like 'Withdrawn' then 'Recreation Leave - Withdrawn'
WHEN DE.Recreation_Leave_Desc like 'Valid Value' then 'Recreation Leave - Valid Value'
END
AS Leave_type_value,
COUNT(Employee_PK) AS Total_Employees FROM
DM.FACT_EMPLOYEE_TEST FE
INNER JOIN
DM.DIM_EMPLOYEE_LEAVE DE
ON FE.Employee_Leave_SK=DE.Employee_Leave_PK
GROUP BY 
[Period], Recreation_Leave_Desc

UNION ALL
SELECT [Period],
Case 
WHEN DE.Carers_Leave_Desc like 'Missing' then 'Carers Leave - Missing'
WHEN DE.Carers_Leave_Desc  like 'Not Applicable' then 'Carers Leave - Not applicable'
WHEN DE.Carers_Leave_Desc  like 'Withdrawn' then 'Carers - Withdrawn'
WHEN DE.Carers_Leave_Desc  like 'Valid Value' then 'Carers - Valid Value'
END
AS Leave_type_value,
COUNT(Employee_PK) AS Total_Employees FROM
DM.FACT_EMPLOYEE_TEST FE
INNER JOIN
DM.DIM_EMPLOYEE_LEAVE DE
ON FE.Employee_Leave_SK=DE.Employee_Leave_PK
GROUP BY 
[Period],Carers_Leave_Desc

`
```

| Period | Leave_type_value | Total_Employees |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | Sick Leave - Missing | 2 |
| 2020 | Sick Leave - Not applicable | 1 |
| 2020 | Sick Leave - Valid Value | 2 |
| 2021 | Sick Leave - Valid Value | 3 |
| 2021 | Sick Leave - Withdrawn | 2 |
| 2020 | Recreation Leave - Missing | 1 |
| 2021 | Recreation Leave - Missing | 2 |
| 2020 | Recreation Leave - Not applicable | 1 |
| 2020 | Recreation Leave - Valid Value | 3 |
| 2021 | Recreation Leave - Valid Value | 1 |
| 2021 | Recreation Leave - Withdrawn | 2 |
| 2020 | Carers Leave - Missing | 2 |
| 2020 | Carers Leave - Not applicable | 1 |
| 2021 | Carers Leave - Not applicable | 1 |
| 2020 | Carers - Valid Value | 2 |
| 2021 | Carers - Valid Value | 4 |

Comment: I don't follow the logic here. Where does the value `15` for `Sick_Leave` in 2020 Missing come from? Take the time to explain your expected results and show us your attempts (and explain why they didn't work).

Comment: Consumable sample data and a fitting expected result would be really nice and helpful here... However, I's start with a CTE / subquery like `SELECT Period, Employee_Leave_SK, COUNT(DISTINCT Employee_PK) AS CountEmp FROM Fact_Employee GROUP BY Period, Employee_Leave_SK`, join it to the dimension and then pivot the result...

Comment: What is "Valid Value"?  "Missing"?  "Withdrawn"?  How are the table connected?

Comment: I don't understand how you know which leave type an employee falls into

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough.  I've updated the question - hope that explains it better.